# MDX - SSAS- calculated measure

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx

I'm having issues when creating a Calculated Measure in the MDX language in Visual Studio. The Calculated Measure should sum the AMOUNTMST from the 1st June 2016 until the period selected by the user, which could be either a year, a month or a date. The measure is the following:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].StockAmount

AS SUM({[Time].[Year - Month - Date].[DATAID].&[2016-06-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Year - Month - Date].currentmember},[Measures].[AMOUNTMST]), 

FORMAT_STRING = "#.##0,00;-#.##0,00", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'F INVENTORY V2'  ;
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Just curious, is your front end Dynamics AX?

Comment: The mdx formula doesn't provide any value (only !VALUE#) on Excel (front end) for the measure when drilling down the time hierarchy at year, month and date level

Comment: to check initially did you try changing this `{[Time].[Year - Month - Date].[DATAID].&[2016-06-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Year - Month - Date].currentmember` to a hard-coded range? e.g.`{[Time].[Year - Month - Date].[DATAID].&[2016-06-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Year - Month - Date].[DATAID].&[2016-08-01T00:00:00]`. I assume if you do this then the VALUES go away?

Comment: But I need to keep the current member because I want the aggregation of the measure at any level I choose ( that might be the year, month or date). The aggregation has to start from that specific date (2016-06-01) though.